# how to disable endless scroll in BasicEditField

Tags: blackberry, textfield, horizontal-scrolling, blackberry-storm, blackberry-basiceditfield

HI all i have implement Custom `BasicEditField` to set hint and to input long text .

please see my code

```
vfm_searchBox = new VerticalFieldManager()
        {
            //Main.Quicksearchinput is background image for inputtext
            public void paint(Graphics g)
            {   
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.drawBitmap(0,0,Main.Quicksearchinput.getWidth(),Main.Quicksearchinput.getHeight(),Main.Quicksearchinput,0,0);
                super.paint(g);
            }}
```

There is one `HorizontalFieldManager` to scroll text.

`hfm_searchBox = new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL) ;`

There is one `Basiceditfield` to input text .

```
txtSearch = new BasicEditField(BasicEditField.NO_NEWLINE)
        {
            public void paint(Graphics g)
            {
                if(super.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                    g.setFont(g.getFont().derive(Font.PLAIN,18));
                    g.drawText("Enter Event title or subtitle", 0, 0);
                    super.paint(g);
                }
                else
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    super.paint(g);
                }

            }};
```

The `BasicEditField` looks nice with `Backgroundimage` and `hint` but problem is that when i am nothing input in textfield it is working as endless scroll . i have set `Horizontalfield` width depend on BasiceditField but  its width by default set to unlimited .

```
hfm_searchBox.add(txtSearch);
vfm_searchBox.add(hfm_searchBox);
```

how to prevent endless scroll ?

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 3):

What is the HorizontalFieldManager's [virtual width](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#getVirtualWidth%28%29)? This refers to the scrollable space whereas the width refers to the extent on the screen. You can try extending HorizontalFieldManager and overriding the sublayout method, calling [setVirtualExtent](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#setVirtualExtent%28int,%20int) in it.

Comment: thanx alot for suggetion. i tried to override method but it is not working . can u plz tell me how to implement this ?

Answer (score 2):

As Tamar said, the Field's **Virtual Width** is the key concept to keep track of.

You can [see my solution to a very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10672365/119114).  I provide a full code example that's probably not too far from what you're trying to do.  The code I use goes a step further, and dynamically limits scrolling only to the end of where the text currently reaches.  If you don't do this, and simply set one constant **virtual width**, then you can have the field actually scroll too far to the right.  By dynamically calling `setVirtualExtent()`, you always get *just enough* scrolling, but not too much.